# C++ `assign()` equivalent in C

Tags: c++, c

Any idea on how can I implement in C the C++ `assign()`?

C++ code sample:

```
std::string ds;
// snip //
ds.assign((const char *)start, end - start);
```

using the same syntax in C I get the following error while compiling:

`error: request for member 'assign' in something not a structure or union`

Comment: This statement ds.assign((const char *)start, end - start); will not be compiled in C++. So I do not understand what you want.

Comment: You said you wanted to implement assign; this code is just trying to use what you have already admitted hasn't been implemented.  And, being C, strings aren't objects and thus don't have methods.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, I'm sure you're wrong.

Comment: @xtmtrx, `char *` is not a class type. You can't call a member function on an instance of it. Perhaps you meant for it to be a `std::string`. I'm also 90% certain that `const char *` cast is either potentially harmful or redundant.

Comment: @xtmtrx: Vlad is 100% correct.

Comment: I need another vote to close the question. Didn't realize a simple question will get a hurricane of down-voting.

Comment: Yeah, everything flows indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use C strings in C, look inside string.h for functions that work with c strings (like strcpy)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: Thank you. I think `strcpy` will do it.

Comment: Work off the examples given in the reference there are some other things like memory allocation that you need to setup (in the example they just do it all on the stack).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you mean the following code snippet

```
std::string ds;
char s[] = "Hello Wotld";
char *start = s;
char *end = s + sizeof( s ) - 1;

ds.assign( start, end - start );
```

In C you deal with raw pointers. So something similar could look the following way

```
char * assign( char *dest, const char *source, size_t n )
{
   free( dest );

   char *p = ( char * )malloc( n + 1 );

   if ( p != NULL )
   {
       strncpy( p, source, n );
       p[n] = '\0';
   }

   dest = p;

   return dest;
}
```

For example

```
char *ds = NULL; // it is important to initialize it to NULL
char s[] = "Hello World";

ds = assign( ds, s, sizeof( s ) - 1 );

//...
free( ds );
```

Comment: Yes, my bad, I meant `std::string ds;`